# DataWindow Error: Row changed between retrieve and update when ran from Windows 2012 R2 server

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am getting an error when updating a DataWindow which says "Row changed between retrieve and update". I am facing this in different environment. When i run my application on Windows 7 machine there is no error thrown. But i run the same application which is hosted on Windows 2012 Server  R2 i am getting this error! 
I am trying to delete a record and update the datawindow after which error is thrown along with Delete query. Strange thing is when i take and run the delete query in the database(SQL Server 2005) it will delete records without any issues.
Please help!! I am beginner in PB using PB 90

Comment: Run a database trace on each db while attempting your delete to see if there is a difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

It was a driver issue, I have configured the app to work with MSS which has resolved my issue.